# magento 2 custom connection needs to be manually closed?

Tags: magento2, database-connection

I have created a second database on the same server as magento database, then I've created a module that fetches data from the second database. In order to fetch data from the second database I have used the

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
```

class in my constructor and then created the connection with:

```
$this->_resourceConnection->getConnection('customConnection');
```

The connection works but once in a while (at random apparently) magento breaks because of "too many connections" errors. So my question is:

- does a new connection get created everytime I call the getConnection() method?
- do I manually have to close the opened custom collections?